# SQL Mark Duplicates on same value and similar date

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, date

I have a table t1 as per below.

The Reg field may be duplicated and the DateSt may be up to 10 minutes apart.

I need to select all duplicate records based on the same Reg column value but only if the DateSt between these values is less than X seconds or minutes etc. Then i need to select just the one...with the highest Conf column value and mark the rest as duplicate.

Can someone please assist with this? Your help would really be appreciated.

```
ID    CamId     DateSt                  AttributeA     Reg      Conf
--    -----     -------                 ----------     ---      ---
80      5    20/12/2013 12:10:57           E         5897HHS     94
81      5    20/12/2013 12:11:03           E         8526FDB     93
82      5    20/12/2013 12:11:17          GBZ        G6746D      98
83      5    20/12/2013 12:11:40           E         3348DGV     93
84      5    20/12/2013 12:11:49          GBZ        G1229       94
85      5    20/12/2013 12:12:05         NONE        2ACF8       67
86      5    20/12/2013 12:12:05         NONE        992FSW      65
87      5    20/12/2013 12:12:05           E         8852FSW     91
88      5    20/12/2013 12:12:17           E         2132TVA     90
89      5    20/12/2013 12:12:33           E         8832BGV     96
90      5    20/12/2013 12:12:34          UK         SS52BGV     87
91      5    20/12/2013 12:12:35           E         9167DLZ     92
92      5    20/12/2013 12:12:35          UK         S6JLZ       72
93      5    20/12/2013 12:12:42           E         5984OXT     95
94      5    20/12/2013 12:12:43          UK         G12VIV      64
```

Comment: is the sql server version sql server 2008 and above?

Comment: Yes. I am using version 2008 and above.

Comment: What do you mean by between these values? Which values, duplicated ones?

Comment: there's no duplicate Reg's though in the data:)  always best to provide a sample source and expected result for these type of questions.

Comment: The Reg number may be duplicate e.g. two rows with reg number 5897HHS but the Date may be several seconds apart

Comment: What's the variation between the dates? Doing datediff by smaller time units (seconds or milliseconds for instance) may in some cases result in overflow errors, in which case the query needs to be organized accordingly. Also, say you have two RegNumber's less than 10 seconds apart, but then there's a third which is more than 10 seconds apart from the first RegNumber Id, but less than 10 from the second, should these be counted as part of the same group?

Comment: Yes..there may be up to 10 duplicates...it would count as a duplicate if the difference between the first and last record is within 5 minutes or so...it can be kept to minutes no need for seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3cc73/12).

This is to be taken as an approach to kick start your thinking, hope it helps.

**Schema and Data Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
  ID     INT,
  CamId  INT,
  DateSt  DATE,
  AttributeA VARCHAR(100),
  Reg  VARCHAR(100),
  Conf INT
  );

INSERT INTO T
VALUES
(90,      5,    GETDATE()-1, 'UK','SS52BGV',8);
INSERT INTO T
VALUES
(90,      5,    GETDATE()-2, 'UK','SS52BGV',44);
INSERT INTO T
VALUES
(90,      5,    GETDATE()-3, 'UK','SS52BGV',3);
INSERT INTO T
VALUES
(90,      5,    GETDATE()-4, 'UK','SS52BGV',5);
INSERT INTO T
VALUES
(90,      5,    GETDATE()-1, 'UK','GHY44',8);
INSERT INTO T
VALUES
(90,      5,    GETDATE()-2, 'UK','GHY44',9);
INSERT INTO T
VALUES
(90,      5,    GETDATE()-3, 'UK','GHY44',66);
INSERT INTO T
VALUES
(90,      5,    GETDATE()-2, 'UK','GHY44',66);
INSERT INTO T
VALUES
(90,      5,    GETDATE()-1, 'UK','KJU13VV',31);
INSERT INTO T
VALUES
(90,      5,    GETDATE()-2, 'UK','KJU13VV',8);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  ID
  ,CAMID
  ,DATEST
  ,ATTRIBUTEA
  ,REG
  ,CONF
  ,CASE WHEN Is_Conf_Max_Dup='Conf_Max' AND ROWN=1 THEN 'Conf_Max' ELSE 'Duplicate' END AS Is_Conf_Max --remove the duplicate Conf values if >=2 rows have the same Max Conf value
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REG ORDER BY CONF DESC, DATEST DESC) AS ROWN
    ,CASE WHEN Conf_Max=Conf THEN 'Conf_Max' ELSE 'Duplicate' END AS Is_Conf_Max_Dup --flag max value of Conf, but duplicate is still possible if 2 rows with same Conf value exists
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
          *
          ,MAX(Conf) OVER (PARTITION BY REG) AS Conf_Max --find max value of Conf
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        ID
        ,CamId
        ,DateSt
        ,AttributeA
        ,Reg
        ,Conf
        ,MIN(DateSt) OVER (PARTITION BY REG) AS DateSt_Min
        ,MAX(DateSt) OVER (PARTITION BY REG) AS DateSt_Max
      FROM T
    ) A 
    WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(dd,DateSt_Max,DateSt_Min)) <= 2 --remove rows which are >2 days apart
  ) B
) C
```

Comment: Thanks...however it does not seem to work when there are over 2 duplicates? Any ideas?